# Multiple Identical 3G modems

Tags: 16.04

I have 3 identical modems being plugged into a usb box.

All 3 USB dongles are detected, and all 3 are provided with an network interface.

The only issue, is only 1 interface is brought online, and provided with it's ip address.

It's really strange, if I manually bring up and assign an IP address the devices work correctly. But really though I need to get ubuntu managing these devices automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, the only was I could get around this for the time being was to use ifconfig to manually bring the interface up. Not ideal but necessary.

ifconfig  up

and then using ifconfig I needed to assign an IP address to it

ifconfig   netmask

then it works... just udev still confused and I'm unable to resolve it.

!!!!!